# Using RecordLinkage to Match Unequal Names Columns in Two Dataframes Before Joining with Dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Below are two dataframes that I would like to join by first and last name using Dplyr.

```
full_join(Names1,Names2,by=c("FirstNames",LastNames")
```

However, there are differences in spelling and within the formats of some of the names. I would like to use RecordLinkage (or adist) to match similar names, and then overwrite the names so that they match in both dataframes before joining. (*I also realize that the "FirstNames" and "LastNames" columns have different titles in both dataframes...so that will have to be changed*.)

```
FirstNames<-c("Chris","Shintaro","Doug","Elsa","Bubbles","Kelly","Christine")
LastNames<-c("MacDougall","Yamazaki","Shapiro","Elizabeth Ray","Murphy","Anderson","Yamaguchi")
Pets<-c("Cat","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat","Snake","Eagle")
Names1<-data.frame(FirstNames,LastNames,Pets)

FirstNames2<-c("Chris","Doug","Shintaro","Bubbles","Elsa")
LastNames2<-c("MacDougal","Shapiro","Yamazaku","Murphy","Elizabeth")
Dwelling<-c("House","House","Apartment","Condo","House")
Names2<-data.frame(FirstNames2,LastNames2,Dwelling)
```

Below are some of the steps I used with the RecordLinkage package, but I encountered an "Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions." Is this because the dataframes have a different number of rows?

```
Results <- compare.linkage(Names1, Names2, blockfld = 1, strcmp = T, exclude = 3)
```

> ```
> PairsSelect <- 
> Results$pairs %>% 
> select(firstNameSim = FirstNames, lastNameSim = LastNames)
> ```

I would like to continue with the code to join the names columns with the PairsSelect data above so that I can find the matches within the first and last name columns and then overwrite both dataframes so that each has the same name spellings and formats before joining. I'm just not sure how to best handle the fact that one dataframe (Names1) contains more rows than the other dataframe (Names2).

Any guidance on how to move forward to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The last names don't perfectly match and `Results$pairs$LastNames` contains non-integer values, which causes the error.  It seems what you really want to do is `Results$pairs[, c("id1", "id2")]` or using `dplyr`: `Results$pairs %>% select(firstNameSim = id1, lastNameSim = id2)`

Comment: Thanks. In the example, "Results$Pairs" is part of a list, but how do I make it a separate dataframe so I can join it to Names1 and Names2?

Comment: I would like to join the tables by first and last name...so the names of the columns will have to be changed.

Comment: Tables only join on perfectly matching key values. Would the first order of business be to compare and align your full names to perfectly match from table to table so that you can us them as a true key to join the tables? Additionally, as the individuals' full names are actually the most atomic unit of unique identity for your tables, would it be most helpful to concatenate them and align fullname to fullname?

Comment: I suppose concatenating the first and last names would be best then as a true key to join the tables.I guess it's better to join two columns instead of four.

Comment: 1/2 the work sounds good. Also, if you add keys would they be helpful later, after you start changing the names, to keep track of who is who from each table?  Then, as you identify which name goes with which name, could you use a table of IDa to IDb as a bridge table/map of ID to ID? Then you could use that to join your tables.

Comment: That sounds good too. Are you able to code it all out? I'm learning a lot for this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept the keys separate from the data going into the 'compare.linkage' function which is a little dodgy from a database worldview, but as long as you don't rearrange the Names relative to the df's before you join the `compare.linkage()` stream back in everything will stay correct.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RecordLinkage)

FirstNames<-c("Chris","Shintaro","Doug","Elsa","Bubbles","Kelly","Christine","Thomas","George")
LastNames<-c("MacDougall","Yamazaki","Shapiro","Elizabeth Ray","Murphy","Anderson","Yamaguchi","DelTorre","Fibonacci")
Pets<-c("Cat","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat","Snake","Eagle","Shark","Parrot")
Names1<-data.frame(FirstNames,LastNames,Pets,FullNames = paste0(FirstNames, " ", LastNames))

FirstNames2<-c("Chris","Doug","Shintaro","Bubbles","Elsa","George")
LastNames2<-c("MacDougal","Shapiro","Yamazaku","Murphy","Elizabeth","Fibos")
Dwelling<-c("House","House","Apartment","Condo","House","Camper")
Names2<-data.frame(FirstNames2,LastNames2,Dwelling,FullNames2 = paste0(FirstNames2, " ", LastNames2))

df1 <- mutate(id1 = row_number(), Names1)
df2 <- mutate(id2 = row_number(), Names2)

Results <- compare.linkage(Names1, Names2, strcmp = T, exclude = c(1:3))

BestResults <- 
    Results$pairs %>% 
    arrange(desc(FullNames))

BestResultsJoined<- 
    full_join(BestResults,df1,by="id1")%>% 
    full_join(df2,by="id2")%>% 
    select(FullNamesSim=FullNames.x,FullNames1=FullNames.y,FullNames2,id1,id2)
BestResultsJoined
```

This gets you a sorted list of closest matches to least closest matches. Looks like you don't want to consider anything getting less than 0.95 similarity (by Jaro-Winkler distance.)

Comment: Thanks again for this. I'm a bit stuck again though when I trying to apply the above code to my actual data. After I run "compare.linkage", the $pairs section doesn't display all my data. One of my dataframe's "FullNames" column has 116 values, and the other dataframe has 107 values. I added unique id's to both, then used Dplyr "select" to pull out just the id columns and full-name columns of the dataframes since I don't think the "exclude" option of RecordLinkage would work since both dataframes have completely different column types. Almost all the entries should match...

Comment: Between the two fullnames columns, there are only about 21 entries that are either misspelled, or that exist in one dataframe but not in the other. However, the results of compare.linkage only shows 35 results, withonly two coded as "1"'s...any ideas as to what is happening? I'm determined to make this process work lol.

Comment: To clarity, compare.linkage only shows 35 results in total...when there should be close to 100, with most matching as perfect "1"'s....

Comment: Did you change argument to `exclude=1` ? That should compare everything but the id's, no?

Comment: also: there was an error in the `exclude` argument in the code above. It was supposed to read `exclude=c(1,4)`. I neglected to update the function after I added in the id's in the Names tables. [wasn't affecting final output, but the results$pairs df was comparing pets to dwellings.] In fact, if you want to exclude all the columns but fullname from the comparison you can just update the code in this example to read `exclude = c(1:4)`. Good idea :-D

Comment: Yeah, I excluded the "exclude" option since my two dataframes consist of only an id column and full-name column. The first dataframe has id1 and FullNames columns, and 107 entries, while the second dataframe has id2 and FullNames columns, with 116 entries. I did an anti-join, and there are only 21 different entries, consisting of either spelling mistakes or entries that are in one dataframe but not in the other. But when I do cmpare.linkage, there are only 35 results in total in the $pairs section...

Comment: I trimmed for leading and trailing white spaces too, just in case. Not sure if that makes a difference or not, also converted both to dataframes, and made sure the id columns were both "as.integer" and the fullnames columns were both "as.character"...so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: You are not alone in confusion now. I added more names to bring the cross product count to 54. The results$pairs tracks along with the change but then on the join something very strange happens. It is popping NA's below 35. I am of the sentiment that the autokeying that the `compare.linkage` is performing is only on the first 35. The full join just shows us the unconnectable tails after that. I knew keying off an autogenerated key is shakey, but I didn't realize it would give out under such a small load... :-|

Comment: Interesting. Any ideas for a solution? Maybe we can try the same data with adist, which might be simpler?

Comment: I'm as equally curious. I've relied heavily on library(stringdist) in the past, and am interested in leveraging RecordLinkage's 'simplicity' more, so I would like to see if I can force the error out of this approach first. Hmmm.

Comment: Cleared the environment and reran code. Discovered that the update was dysfunctional after all adjustment and recognized I needed to build fullnames on the Names tables instead of in the dataframes: have swapped in the improved code above.

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but I'm stuck again at the "compare.linkage" command. I keep getting an error - "Data sets have different format". Could it be because my actual dataframes do not have the same number of columns? If I include the new "FullNames" columns, one dataframe has 8 columns, and the other has 11 columns.

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with the row counts when you join. It is the classes of the columns most likely. Use `glimpse(Names1)` to examine each of the column types.

Comment: Is it possible to see the adist option again too with this set of data? lol

Comment: It would be fun, but I won't be able to get to that until tomorrow. I think you should be a hairsbreadth from complete on the record linkage method though. It is just type juggling that needs to happen from what I can tell.

Comment: What should I be looking for with glimpse? All the names columns are character, so they match.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Which column are you using to join the tables/datasets?

Comment: I'm not joining yet, I'm stuck at: "Results <- compare.linkage(Names1, Names2, strcmp = T)"

Comment: Do the column titles have to match on the original dataframes, or do they have to be different...like FirstName and LastName for the first dataframe, and FirstName2 and LastName2 for the second dataframe? Or can both just have FirstName, LastName? Not sure if this affects anything...

Comment: Ah. So then yes, for the compare linkage you will need to make the column counts equal (so that you can make a square matrix to compare something.x to something.y each time. Since you are trying to just map between FullNames, do you want to compare just the fullnames to each other?

Comment: slice the fullnames off of each, and compare.linkage() those to make your mapping of id1 to id2 like in the code. (If you then run an id down your wide tables just like I did for the df1 and df2, you can join all three of your tables together happily.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly right. Build intermediate dataframes so that you can construct the bridge table/mapping table/ record Linkage table. You will use that in the end to glue your two large tables together. :-D

Comment: Yay! I made it work. It was that missing step of slicing off the fullnames columns. So now I have to learn how to work with the results? If I filter for >.95, I miss some. For example, there is a match at .88, but the two above this match are incorrect. And it pairs every type of combination, so there are over 11,000 attempted matches lol. How do I know when to cut off? I guess there will always be some that are lost? I'm just not sure why the .88 match is below some that are incorrect...I guess this is the world of fuzzy matching? It's all new to me.

Comment: Yes indeed! Job security :-D. But at least the columns are sorted so you can bop down the list and carve out/purge the losers, tweak the ties, and find exactly at which level (about) it is best to dump the tailings.

Comment: Yeah. For instance, there are two names that are off by the same amount of letters...one is "Chris" and "Christopher", and the other is "Alex" and "Alexandros". Both of their last names were perfect matches, but Chris came in at .89, and Alex came in at .88, but has two incorrect matches above him. Shouldn't Alex be under Chris? I don't understand the logic there. But I guess I can play with it.

Comment: this is where two(or more) screens and a call to `write.csv(dataname, "dataname.csv", na = "", row.names = F)` are useful. Pick the file up in excel. Shift + space, Ctrl + - your way to perfection. Then call the file back in with `Dataframe <- read.csv("Dataframe.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c("", " ", "NA"))` - like in that earlier adist example

Comment: And lol, what happens to the names that were only in one dataframe and had no matches? I guess I can't easily find them? This would happen in the case of a full_join, but I guess I could just do a left_join instead so I don't have to worry about them.

Comment: That is where the id's really show off their reason for being :-D

Comment: I guess I can use the Excel method. I guess this is how fuzzy mathing is typically done? It's quite the process to get used to. I greatly appreciate all your help and patience though! It would be great to still see an adist example, no rush lol Also, I found a package "fuzzyjoin", are you familar with it? It sounds promising as well.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I was finally able to accept your code above lol.

Comment: This is Advanced fuzzy matching :-D Full Strength and Free - you should see what big business pays for tools that basically do nothing more than you just did. https://www.informatica.com/products/master-data-management/identity-resolution.html#fbid=QjbQkjxpMkR
or they hire legions of folks to review excel spreadsheets and database records a la *mechanical turk - variant offshore*.

fuzzyjoin is a new one for me. Looking forward to digging into it. Thanks for the tip off!

Comment: Haven't forgotten about trying the adist example: have just gotten really busy. Looking forward to trying it even if the levenshtein results may not be as typically effective as the jaro-winkler - though they work well for names that must fall in proper sequence.